# UnicodeDecodeError: Python

Tags: python, unicode

I am getting this error.
I am not sure whether it is my mistake or something else.
I am on python 3.X version right now.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Administrator/Desktop/A2_b/author_program.py", line 104, in <module>
    signature = read_signature(dir_name + "/" + this_file)
  File "/Users/Administrator/Desktop/A2_b/author_program.py", line 48, in read_signature
    result = [sig_file.readline().strip()]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 3131: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Here is the code that gives me this error. I only had to complete in this file first and second function.

```
import author_functions, os.path

def get_valid_filename(msg):
    """ (str) -> str

    Prompt the user, using msg, to type the name of a file. This file should 
    exist in the same directory as the starter code. If the file does not
    exist, keep re-prompting until they give a valid filename.
    Return the name of that file.
    """
    filename = input(msg)
    while not os.path.exists(filename):
        print("That file does not exist.")
        filename = input(msg)

    return filename


def get_valid_directory_name(msg):
    """ (str) -> str

    Prompt the user, using msg, to type the name of a directory. If
    the directory does not exist, keep re-prompting until they give a valid
    directory. 
    Return the name of that directory.
    """
    dirname = input(msg)

    while not os.path.isdir(dirname):
        print("That directory does not exist.")
        dirname = input(msg)

    return dirname


### Provided helper function ###

def read_signature(filename):
    """ (str) -> list

    Read a linguistic signature from filename and return it as 
    a list of features. 
    """

    sig_file = open(filename, 'r')

    # Read the first feature.
    result = [sig_file.readline().strip()]

    # Read each remaining feature and convert each one to float.
    for line in sig_file:
        result.append(float(line.strip()))

    sig_file.close()

    return result    


# #############################
# The main program begins here 
# #############################

if __name__ == '__main__':

    prompt = 'Enter the name of the file with unknown author: '
    mystery_filename = get_valid_filename(prompt)

    prompt = 'Enter the name of the directory of signature files: '
    dir_name = get_valid_directory_name(prompt)

    # Every file in the dir_name directory must be a linguistic signature. 
    # We assume there is a minimum of one file.
    files = os.listdir(dir_name)

    # ####################################################################
    # The following code parses the mystery file and calculates its 
    # linguistic signature.                                         
    # ####################################################################

    mystery_file = open(mystery_filename, 'r')
    # readlines() gives us a list of strings, one for each line of the file
    text = mystery_file.readlines()
    mystery_file.close()

    # Calculate the signature for the mystery file
    mystery_signature = [mystery_filename]
    mystery_signature.append(author_functions.avg_word_length(text))
    mystery_signature.append(author_functions.type_token_ratio(text))
    mystery_signature.append(author_functions.hapax_legomena_ratio(text))
    mystery_signature.append(author_functions.avg_sentence_length(text))
    mystery_signature.append(author_functions.avg_sentence_complexity(text))

    # ####################################################
    # The following code reads the linguistic signatures, 
    # compares them with the mystery_signature,           
    # and reports the author that was the best match.                   
    # ####################################################

    # Weights of linguistic features.
    weights = [0, 11, 33, 50, 0.4, 4]

    # We assume there is at least one signature in the dir_name directory
    this_file = files[0]
    signature = read_signature(dir_name + "/" + this_file)
    best_score = author_functions.compare_signatures(mystery_signature,
                                                     signature, weights)
    best_author = signature[0]

    for this_file in files[1:]:
        signature = read_signature(dir_name + "/" + this_file)
        score = author_functions.compare_signatures(mystery_signature,
                                                    signature, weights)
        if score < best_score:
            best_score = score
            best_author = signature[0]

    if type(best_score) != float:
        print("Error! No score could be computed")
    else:
        print("Best author match:", best_author, "with score", best_score)
```

Answer (score 2):

try  `sig_file = open(filename, 'rb')`

the `b` means there is binary data in the file (not just ascii)

that will probably resolve your issue

Comment: @b8ckwith it may eliminate the error, but it's not correct. The file appears to be a text file so you should open it as such, but you need to know the encoding for the non-ASCII characters.

Comment: I don't understand, can you explain it differently?

Comment: @MarkRansom he has non-ascii characters in it clearly since it is throwing the exception on `readline` (and assuming its utf-8 encoded python *should* just do the right thing  ... note that I am not sure, since I dont really use python3 ... but thats how I understand it

Comment: @b8ckwith it's obviously not ASCII. It's also not UTF-8, since the first non-ASCII character wouldn't be 0x80 if it was. That leaves a whole bunch of possibilities, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page. You *need* to know which is the proper one before you can open the file as it was intended. Opening as binary masks the problem and leaves you with an unintelligible character in your string.